# params get value when directly place in is not executing

Tags: parameters

Need help as unable to directly place value
Below is code for paytm payment gateway integration

```
define('PAYTM_TRANSACTION_URL', $params->get('paytm_transaction_url')); // transaction url
define('PAYTM_TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL', $params->get('paytm_transaction_status_url')); // transaction status url
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', $params->get('paytm_merchant_key')); //Change this constant's value with Merchant key downloaded from portal
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', $params->get('paytm_merchant_mid')); //Change this constant's value with MID (Merchant ID) received from Paytm
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', $params->get('paytm_merchant_website')); //Change this constant's value with Website name received from Paytm
```

Howeverm when i directly try to place value to hard code

```
define('PAYTM_TRANSACTION_URL', 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction'); // transaction url
define('PAYTM_TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL', 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus'); // transaction status url
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', 'xxddjhdBBaeM3'); //Change this constant's value with Merchant key received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', 'qwsjdhnnd634'); //Change this constant's value with MID (Merchant ID) received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'https://www.example.com'); //Change this constant's value with Website name received from Paytm.
```

This is showing error as invalid key, id
i checked multiple times both key and mid are same as in database which is what put in when directly placing same. Am i putting it wrong with '' or how to rewrite same,
pl advise. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using incorrect PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID and PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY. Kindly login to paytm dashboard to get the correct paytm credentials (MID, Merchant Key).